# c#/linq data grouping

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a Product class something like:

```
class Product
{
  public string Name;
  public int Year;
  public int Vendor;
  public int Count;
}
```

Data input like

```
Name Year Vendor Count

'A'  1990   1     15

'A'  1990   2     20

'A'  1998   4     5

'B'  1995   1     15

'B'  1995   2     2
```

I want to transform the data into a new structure like

```
class NewStructure
{
 public string Name;
 public int Year;
 Dictionary<int, int> Vendor_Count;
}
```

The Dictionary field is used to store {Vendor, Count} pair, the pair of Name and Year would have a correspodning dictionary. The result would be

```
Name Year Vendor Count

'A'  1990   1  15

            2  20

'A'  1998   4  5

'B'  1995   1  15

            2   2
```

I tried the following linq query

```
from input in inputList
group inputList by new { input.Name, input.Year }
into grouping
orderby grouping.Key.Name, grouping.Key.Year
select new
{
   ProductName = grouping.Key.Name,
   OriginYear = grouping.Key.Year,
   Vendor_Count = grouping.
 }
```

But I can't get the 'Vendor_Count' right. I wonder what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
        var p1 = new Product(){Count=15, Name="A", Vendor = 1, Year = 1990};
        var p2 = new Product() { Count = 20, Name = "A", Vendor = 2, Year = 1990 };
        var p3 = new Product() { Count = 5, Name = "A", Vendor = 4, Year = 1998 };
        var p4 = new Product() { Count = 15, Name = "B", Vendor = 1, Year = 1995 };
        var p5 = new Product() { Count = 2, Name = "B", Vendor = 1, Year = 1995 };

        var inputList = new[] {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5};

        var newStructure = inputList
            .GroupBy( p => new { p.Name, p.Year } )
            .Select( g => new { g.Key.Name, g.Key.Year, VendorCount = g.ToDictionary(p => p.Vendor, p => p.Count) }
          );
```

Although I don't think you can use Vendor as a dictionary key, because they are not unique as it stands

Comment: In the data in the original question Name/Vendor/Year form a unique set. Your set B has two Vendor ones for 95. This may be possible in the data but it isn't in the original spec... Thus this seems to work perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this if the combination of (Name, Year, Vendor) is unique:

```
inputList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Year })
         .Select(x => new
                      {
                          ProductName = x.Key.Name,
                          OriginYear = x.Key.Year, 
                          Vendor_Count = x.ToDictionary(y => y.Vendor
                                                        y => y.Count)
                      })
         .OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ThenBy(x => x.OriginYear);
```

Use this if it isn't unique:

```
inputList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Year })
         .Select(x => new
                      {
                          ProductName = x.Key.Name,
                          OriginYear = x.Key.Year, 
                          Vendor_Count = x.GroupBy(y => y.Vendor)
                                          .ToDictionary(y => y.Key,
                                                        y => y.Sum(z => z.Count))
                      })
         .OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ThenBy(x => x.OriginYear);
```

Comment: would x be List<Product> rather than Product. It seems to be a list and I got error.

Comment: This time I got 'An item with the same key has already been added.'

Comment: @esun203: Please see update. Now it works correctly, even when the combination of (Name, Year, Vendor) is not unique. I was totally confused about the query syntax because I never use it.